# Как вывести первый элемент из коллекции ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Есть модель новостей, там коллекция картинок (их несколько штук для каждой новости). Надо вывести только первую картинку из этой коллекции.

Так выглядит модель:

```
public class NewsViewModelItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ShortTitle { get; set; }
    public string FullTitle { get; set; }
    public string ShortArticle { get; set; }
    public string FullArticle { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NewsImageModelItem> NewsImages { get; set; }

}

public class NewsImageModelItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageItem { get; set; }
    public int NewsId { get; set; }

}

public class PageInfo
{
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages
    {
        get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItems / PageSize); }
    }
}

public class NewsViewModel
{
    public List<NewsViewModelItem> News { get; set; }
    public PageInfo PageInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Чтоб вывести все картинки я использую такую конструкцию:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.News)
{
   @foreach (var img in item.NewsImages){
      //тут выводятся все картинки
      <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(img.ImageItem)" />
   }
}
```

**Вопрос:** Как вывести только первую картинку?

Comment: Заместо цикла используйте 
[FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb908820%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) `item.NewsImages.FirstOrDefault().ImageItem`, вроде так. либо можно попробовать по номеру объекта `item.NewsImages[0].ImageItem`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `item.NewsImages.FirstOrDefault().ImageItem` именно то, что мне нужно. Спасибо! Напишите сообщение в ответы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заместо цикла используйте [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb908820%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) `item.NewsImages.FirstOrDefault().ImageItem`, вроде так. Либо можно попробовать по номеру объекта `item.NewsImages[0].ImageItem`.

Comment: В вашем решении с `FirstOrDefault` можно наткнуться на `NullReferenceException`. Нужно либо `?.` использовать, либо проверку на `Any` и `First`.

Comment: @Vlad Я думаю, что с этим уже люди разбируться) Но за дополнение, спасибо.

Comment: @Vlad, действительно наткнулся на `NullReferenceException` и сделал проверки.